# Docker ELK : Can't move to stopped state when not started

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elk

I try to implement a docker compose file for ELK and i want to use the stack with springboot microservices that are not containerized actually :

- I added a setup service which aims to create certificates and set the applications up

Here is my setup service:

```
  setup:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    volumes:
      - ./certs/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
    user: "0"
    command: >
      bash -c '
        if [ x${ELASTIC_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the ELASTIC_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        elif [ x${KIBANA_PASSWORD} == x ]; then
          echo "Set the KIBANA_PASSWORD environment variable in the .env file";
          exit 1;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/ca.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating CA";
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil ca --silent --pem -out config/certs/ca.zip;
          unzip config/certs/ca.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        if [ ! -f config/certs/certs.zip ]; then
          echo "Creating certs";
          echo -ne \
          "instances:\n"\
          "  - name: elasticsearch\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - elasticsearch\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          "  - name: kibana\n"\
          "    dns:\n"\
          "      - kibana\n"\
          "      - localhost\n"\
          "    ip:\n"\
          "      - 127.0.0.1\n"\
          > config/certs/instances.yml;
          bin/elasticsearch-certutil cert --silent --pem -out config/certs/certs.zip --in config/certs/instances.yml  --ca-cert config/certs/ca/ca.crt --ca-key config/certs/ca/ca.key;
          unzip config/certs/certs.zip -d config/certs;
        fi;
        echo "Setting file permissions"
        chown -R root:root config/certs;
        find . -type d -exec chmod 750 \{\} \;;
        find . -type f -exec chmod 640 \{\} \;;
        echo "Waiting for Elasticsearch availability";
        until curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://elasticsearch:9200 | grep -q "missing authentication credentials"; do sleep 30; done;
        echo "Setting kibana_system password";
        until curl -s -X POST --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt -u "elastic:${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}" -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://elasticsearch:9200/_security/user/kibana_system/_password -d "{\"password\":\"${KIBANA_PASSWORD}\"}" | grep -q "^{}"; do sleep 10; done;
        echo "All done!";
      '
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "[ -f config/certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt ]" ]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 120
```

My 3 other services have the following configuration:

```
  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:${STACK_VERSION}
    container_name: elasticsearch
    depends_on:
        setup:
          condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./certs/elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/certs
      - ./elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
      - ./elasticsearch/logs:/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/
    ports:
      - '9200:9200'
    environment:
      - ELASTIC_USERNAME=${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_URL=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=http://elasticsearch:9200
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - xpack.security.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.key=certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.key
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate=certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt
      - xpack.security.http.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.enabled=true
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.key=certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.key
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate=certs/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.certificate_authorities=certs/ca/ca.crt
      - xpack.security.transport.ssl.verification_mode=certificate
      - xpack.license.self_generated.type=${LICENSE}
      - ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms2g -Xmx2g
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s --cacert config/certs/ca/ca.crt https://localhost:9200 | grep -q 'missing authentication credentials'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120

  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${STACK_VERSION}
    container_name: logstash
    depends_on:
      setup:
        condition: service_healthy
      elasticsearch:
        condition: service_healthy
      kibana:
        condition: service_healthy
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/data:/usr/share/logstash/data
      - ./certs/logstash:/usr/share/logstash/certs
      - ./logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf:ro
    environment:
      - xpack.monitoring.enabled=false
      - ELASTIC_USER=${ELASTIC_USERNAME}
      - ELASTIC_PASSWORD=${ELASTIC_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTIC_HOSTS=https://elasticsearch:9200
    command: logstash -f /usr/share/logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf
    ports:
      - "5044:5044/udp"

  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:${STACK_VERSION}
    container_name: kibana
    depends_on:
      elasticsearch:
        condition: service_healthy
    volumes:
      - ./certs/kibana:/usr/share/kibana/config/certs
      - ./kibana/data:/usr/share/kibana/data
    ports:
      - ${KIBANA_PORT}:5601
    environment:
      - SERVERNAME=kibana
      - ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS=https://elasticsearch:9200
      - ELASTICSEARCH_USERNAME=kibana_system
      - ELASTICSEARCH_PASSWORD=${KIBANA_PASSWORD}
      - ELASTICSEARCH_SSL_CERTIFICATEAUTHORITIES=config/certs/ca/ca.crt
      - XPACK_SECURITY_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - XPACK_ENCRYPTEDSAVEDOBJECTS_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
      - XPACK_REPORTING_ENCRYPTIONKEY=${ENCRYPTION_KEY}
    healthcheck:
      test:
        [
          "CMD-SHELL",
          "curl -s -I http://localhost:5601 | grep -q 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found'",
        ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 120
```

My logstash configuration aims to retrieve local files :

```
input {
    file {
        type => "users-ws-log"
        path => "D:/logs/users-ws.log"
    }
    file {
        type => "accounts-ws-log"
        path => "D:/logs/accounts-ws.log"
    }
}
output {
    if [type] == "users-ws-log" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
            index => "users-ws-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "elastic123"
            ssl_enabled => true
            cacert => "/usr/share/logstash/certs/ca/ca.crt"
        }
    }
    else if [type] == "accounts-ws-log" {
        elasticsearch {
            hosts => ["https://localhost:9200"]
            index => "accounts-ws-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
            user => "elastic"
            password => "elastic123"
            ssl_enabled => true
            cacert => "/usr/share/logstash/certs/ca/ca.crt"
        }
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

Now my issue is the following, when running docker compose I do have the following error:

```
elasticsearch  | {"@timestamp":"2023-12-10T19:23:29.623Z", "log.level": "WARN", "message":"unexpected exception while waiting for http server to close", "ecs.version": "1.2.0","service.name":"ES_ECS","event.dataset":"elasticsear
ch.server","process.thread.name":"Thread-0","log.logger":"org.elasticsearch.node.Node","elasticsearch.node.name":"d7caa4369528","elasticsearch.cluster.name":"docker-cluster","error.type":"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException"
,"error.message":"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move to stopped state when not started","error.stack_trace":"java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move to stopped state when not
 started\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.node.Node.prep
areForClose(Node.java:1776)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.shutdown(Elasticsearch.java:468)\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalSta
teException: Can't move to stopped state when not started\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.common.component.Lifecycle.canMoveToStopped(Lifecycle.java:128)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elastics
earch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.stop(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:73)\n\tat org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$prepareForClose$59(Node.java:1768)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)\n\t... 1 more\n"}
```

Here's a better-formatted copy of the error

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move to stopped state when not
 started
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.node.Node.prepareForClose(Node.java:1776)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.shutdown(Elasticsearch.java:468)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't move to stopped state when not started
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.common.component.Lifecycle.canMoveToStopped(Lifecycle.java:128)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.common.component.AbstractLifecycleComponent.stop(AbstractLifecycleComponent.java:73)
    at org.elasticsearch.server@8.11.2/org.elasticsearch.node.Node.lambda$prepareForClose$59(Node.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:317)
    ... 1 more

Stack trace made readable by https://TidyTrace.com
```

Comment: I reverted my elasticsearch.yaml to default and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This certainly has to do with os-rights on your data volume and docker bind volumes.
Try running the same compose file with the datavolumes unexposed.